# JavaScript function only works on index.html

Tags: javascript, html

I've built a practice website that has multiple pages.  The home page is `index.html.`  I wrote a JS function that changes the `opacity` of the header when scrolling down.  For some reason it will only work on `index.html`, no other pages on the site.  All the other functions I've written do work on all pages.  I've been reading to see if it has something to do with page loading but I really can't find anything concrete. Can anyone give any insight as to why this particular function only works on `index.html`.

CSS for the header

```
header {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  background: var(--white-background);
  border-bottom: 2px solid #f1f1f1;
  font-family: var(--company-font);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .5s;
  z-index: 10;
}
```

The function in question

Even the `console.log()` at the end is only working on `index.html`

```
function checkHeaderScroll() {
  if(document.location.pathname == '/index.html')  {
    if (window.pageYOffset > 10) {
      header[0].style.opacity = '1';
      logo.style.opacity = '0';
      logo.style.transform = 'translateY(-250%)';
    } else if (window.pageYOffset < 10) {
      header[0].style.opacity = '0';
      logo.style.opacity = '1';
      logo.style.transform = 'translateY(0)';
    }
  } else {
    header[1].style.opacity = '1';
  }
}
window.addEventListener('scroll', checkHeaderScroll);

console.log("hello");
```

Comment: `if(document.location.pathname == '/index.html')`...

Comment: I assume you mean when the else condition is met on pages other than `index.html`? why `header[1]` instead of `header[0]`?

Comment: @pokeybit  I originally had `header[0]` and it didn't work so I was seeing if it had something to do with HTML collection.  lt didnt work with `header[0]` either.

Answer (score 0):

This is because of line 2 in the checkHeaderScroll() function:-

`if(document.location.pathname == '/index.html')  {`

if you remove line 2, 12, 13 and 14 this should work on all of your pages.

So your new function looks like:-

```
function checkHeaderScroll() {
    if (window.pageYOffset > 10) {
      header[0].style.opacity = '1';
      logo.style.opacity = '0';
      logo.style.transform = 'translateY(-250%)';
    } else if (window.pageYOffset < 10) {
      header[0].style.opacity = '0';
      logo.style.opacity = '1';
      logo.style.transform = 'translateY(0)';
    }
}
window.addEventListener('scroll', checkHeaderScroll);
```

Comment: `@hensler Software`  I'm not sure why the `console.log()` won't work on other pages either.  Its outside the function.

Comment: Are you calling the js file on the other pages?

Comment: I am.  I have several other functions that add functionality to the navigation and also check for a window resize and they work on all other pages.

Comment: I'm getting TypeErrors on unrelated functions but thats it.

Comment: My first incarnation of the function is actually the one you wrote in you answer but it didn't work.  I only added the `location.pathname` to see if it would do anything in regards to the other pages

Comment: It would probably be best if you provided an example on jsFiddle, we can't debug something we can't see.

Answer (score 0):

You stated that the function only will work on index.html, in the line:
if(document.location.pathname == '/index.html'). Thus not working on other pages.